# How to stay in view when searching by filter

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

I've added *Owner* to the columns shown in the standard *Active Accounts* view, as well as some other fields. This turned out as supposed to. However, I've noticed that when I enter something in the search box on the right, the filtering gets me a correct list of accounts **but** the columns are not the ones that I've set in the view *Active Accounts*.

Where do I set it to be like that? Preferably so that CRM retains the subset of columns and only filter down the number of records presented. If it's not possible, how do I set the columns presented in the *Search Results* view (independently of from which view the search's been performed)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In solution, on where entity views are listed, there is 'quick find' type view. Columns defined in tha view are displayed when search is executed.

You can also define additional search criteria for search, when you modify filter in that view.

Comment: Is there a way to have different columns (view columns) dependent on which view that we have active prior to the search? I know that the result is created from the search box but for a user, it feels like they filter down the list that they see **right now** and it confuses them when the number/order of columns suddenly changes when they "*did nothing new*"...

Comment: Well... If you **are** then let us know... (I'm sensing a typo here, though. You forgot to add a *not*, didn't you, Mario?)   :)

Comment: yeah, just a typo, there is no secret that i have to keep to myself :) Cannot edit other comment so i'll just delete and confirm that "i'm NOT aware of such possibility"

Comment: "*Typ**o***", not "*typ**e***", mate. You've had a long day, right?   :)   Thanks a million, bro.